# Does one convolutional filter always have different coefficients for each of the channels of the previous layer?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution, cudnn

For example, we have RGB-image with 3 channels (Red, Green, Blue). And we use convolutional neural network.

Does each convolutional filter always have 3 different coefficients for each of the channels (R,G,B) of image?

1. I.e. does filter-W1 has 3 different coefficient matrices: `W1[::0], W1[::1], W1[::2]` as shown in the picture below?
2. Or are often used the same coefficients in one filter in modern neural networks (`W1[::0] = W1[::1] = W1[::2]`)?

[image]

Taken by link: http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/

---

Also: http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#conv

> Convolutional Layer
>
> ...
>
> The extent of the **connectivity along the depth axis is always equal to
>   the depth of the input volume. It is important** to emphasize again this
>   asymmetry in how we treat the spatial dimensions (width and height)
>   and the depth dimension: The connections are local in space (along
>   width and height), but **always full along the entire depth of the input
>   volume**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what is represented is the first hidden (here convolutional layer). Every single filter has a 3 channels because your input (for this layer your images) has 3 channels (RGB). Resulting in 2 feature maps that you concatenate (that explains the Output Volume of (3x3)x2 size).

More generally, for an input of (for simplicity let's consider a batche size of 1) of size (1x)WxHxC, every filter will have a size of NxNxC (for simplicity let's consider a stride of 1 and a 'SAME' padding even if for your example it is a 'VALID' padding), so for F filters yout output will have a size of (1x)WxHxF.

Hope it is clear enough (for your example W = H = 7, C = 3, N = 3 and F = 2).

Do not hesitate to comment if it is not clear enough :)

Comment: Thank you! Those. With the standard classical use of convolutional networks, the filter always has the size of NхNхC (in my case 3x3x3). Can you explain, what does mean 'SAME' padding and 'VALID' padding, and how are they different?

Comment: Same padding is when you pad your input with a value (in most cases, people do zero-padding) so you can apply your convolution even on the edges. So with 'SAME' padding you end up with an output of size WxHxF (same size of your input for spatial dimensions) if you do 'VALID' padding it means that you don't pad with zeros (so you can't treat pixels on the edge) so you end up with an output of size W-(N-1)xH-(N-1)xF.
Take a look at this video (especially from 2:45 for padding explaination) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jajksuQW4mc